# Getting data from a .json URL [Xamarin]

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I'm currently developing an application to grab .json data from an URL and show it to a ListView on Xamarin.

Here is the URL : https://www.mrniato.com/mysql_to_json.php
I would like to grab all the "Firmware".

I need help on what code to use to show them on the ListView.

I've already tried some code found on the internet but without success...

Thanks you for your answers.

Comment: `I need help on what code` show what you tried, tell us what is the problem exactly, and we will try to help.

Comment: I don't know what to do, in fact I've deleted all the code that didn't worked. The goal is to grab the data from the json and show it into a listview in Xamarin without error

Comment: then you have to try something first, and then if there are any problems - ask a question. If you don't know where to start - start from searching on how to get data from the internet in XAMARIN

Comment: I agree with @VladyslavMatviienko. Though I can give you a push in the right direction. Take a look at the `HttpClient` class. You need this to get the data from the URL. When you successfully retreived your data you need to populate your `ListView` with the data. You can read more about doing that over here: [Populating a Xamarin.Android ListView With Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating). Try a bit yourself and post the code you tried if you can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use **HttpClient** to request your data,here is a simple snippet for `Get`request from server:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()){ 
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Grab grab = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grab>(content);
                List<Grab.Date> dates = grab.PS4_Beta;
                foreach (var item in dates)
                {
                    Log.Error("Firmware", "==" + item.Firmware);
                }
        }
```

the `content` is which your server return you.you could convert it to your custom data model with **Newtonsoft.Json** nuget.

for example the model like :

```
class Grab 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PS4_Beta")]
    public List<Data> PS4_Beta{ get; set; }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Firmware")]
        public string Firmware { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Size")]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MD5")]
        public string MD5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

you could refer to [Consuming REST Services With HttpClient](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-consuming-rest-services-with-httpclient/)

and finally you could display with ListView by JKL's link above.

**ListView :**

```
   Grab grab = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grab>(content);
   List<Grab.Date> dates = grab.PS4_Beta;
   ObservableCollection<string> FirmwareList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   foreach (var item in dates)
       {
          FirmwareList.Add(item.Firmware);
       }
   listView.ItemSource = FirmwareList ;
```

Comment: Alright, I managed to get some JSON data but they are not in order, for now I only want to grab the Firmware.   Picture of the app : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568881115-70917380-490759611656368-5253529495964483584-n.png and the code : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568881195-capture.png

Comment: yes ,you have get the data string which server return you,you should convert the json string  to your model.

Comment: I think I'm almost here but now it show nothing on the app.... maybe I've done something wrong ? The data is converted to JSON and then I ask the app to grab "Firmware" : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568882044-capture.png

Comment: @GuillaumeMrNiato my mistake,you could define your Grab class like MyData above

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568882943-capture.png it still return nothing :/

Comment: @GuillaumeMrNiato change the Grab like above

Comment: Alright, now it has shown 7.00 Beta 5 in the label which is pretty cool ! Now how can I grab everything into a listView ? The listview is already prepared but I need to know how to SetValue in the listView or show all the beta ? because it only show one at the moment ? Thanks

Comment: @GuillaumeMrNiato check above,use arrayadapter to show your Firmware list

Comment: I think we're almost there ! https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568884914-70352980-969222363423980-4708908719205777408-n.png all is show in a Picker but in a ListView it only show 1 firmware :/ https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568884913-71278882-519973352123237-3327406001384062976-n.png  here is the code : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/38/4/1568885017-capture.png

Comment: @GuillaumeMrNiato you should put   `itemList = new ObserableCollection<string>() ` and  `gradb.ItemSource = itemList ` outside the foreach,like above i update

Comment: Everything is clear now, thanks you for your time !